# In a graph, how do you determine if two vertices form a bridge and which vertices will be part of which subgraph once the bridge is disconnected?

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, adjacency-list

I'm using an adjacency list to create my graph in C#.

[image]

In this graph, #4 and #5 form a bridge that when disconnected will create two subgraphs:

- {1,2,3,4}
- {5,6,7,8}

My question is two parts:

1. How do I determine if #4 and #5 form a bridge?
2. How do I find out which vertices belong to which subgraph so that I can create new graphs for each of the subgraph?

Comment: I'm thinking I'll have to: 1) Remove the edge connecting #4 and #5 2) Use depth-first search to determine if #4 is connected to #5 3) If they are not connected, they form a bridge 4) Use DFS again, starting with #4 and add all captured to a new graph 5) Do again but for #5. Would that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all bridges in a graph in `O(V+E)` , [read here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/)

After that, mark the bridges and find the connected components using DFS:

```
for each node:
        if (not visited)
            components++
            dfs(node)
```

In the dfs traversal don't pass through edges that are marked as bridges.

Comment: Do I have to find all bridges in a graph first? Or would it be ok to check if a single edge is a bridge, remove that edge (because I have to anyways), set the vertices that form the bridge to be a root, and then DFS starting with the root and adding to a list of what is crawled? Would that give me the subgraphs I want?

Comment: You can do that, but you would need to do that for every edge in the graph, so your complexity would become O(E*(V+E))

Comment: If I first find a list of all bridges in a graph, can't I just run a DFS on the two vertices that form a bridge? Because I'll know that the edge between the two vertices when broken will form two subgraphs. I'll just run a DFS with the starting vertex being the vertex that the bridge edge was connected to, and adding reachable vertexes into a list. I'll end up with two lists which will give me the vertices in the two subgraphs. Does that work?

Comment: You can do that for each bridge, it would be the same complexity O(V+E). But make sure you check if a node is visited before starting a traversal from it since each component can be surrounded by more than 1 bridge

Comment: Is that you mean by the 2nd line of your answer? Where would I mark it as visited? In the 'dfs' function?

Comment: normally in dfs you would mark each node as visited when you reach it, lets say we have a graph A<->B<->C , here both edges are bridges, so you take the first edge (A-B) and perform dfs on A and on B, next you take the other edge (B-C) you perform dfs on C, but since B is already visited you dont perform dfs again on it.